Highlight all keywords entered into input box, rather than just the first keyword identified
I'm developing a macro that can be run to check the compliance of line item descriptions against client billing requirements. Certain words and symbols shouldn't be included in these descriptions and can vary month to month.
I have the following code which works well to highlight the non-compliant cells and identify which words and symbols need to be removed/updated.
Unfortunately, it only colours the first instance of a keyword entered into the input box. If the word or symbol occurs multiple times in the same cell then any of the subsequent instances in that same cell aren't coloured red.
Sub HighlightInputBoxText()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strSearch As String
Dim UserRange As Range
Dim arySearch As Variant
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long, ii As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Narratives")
Set UserRange = ws.Range("N2:N10")

    strSearch = InputBox("Please enter text to highlight as a comma delimited list e.g. Abc,Xyz:", "Highlight Non-compliant Text")

    If strSearch = "" Then Exit Sub
    arySearch = Split(strSearch, ",")


    For Each cell In UserRange
        With cell
        For ii = LBound(arySearch) To UBound(arySearch)
        i = InStr(UCase(cell.Value), UCase(arySearch(ii)))
            If i > 0 Then
                cell.Characters(i, Len(arySearch(ii))).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)
            End If
        Next ii
        End With
    Next cell

End Sub


I have tried to use a loop to set the font colour for all instances in a call, then InStr function to return the position of the first occurrence of one string within another and then use the Substitute function to replace the first instance with the same amount of space, but I haven't been able to get this working with the input array.
Any guidance/assistance would be appreciated thank you!

You will need a third loop inside the two loops you already have to search for all occurrences of a word inside the string.
The Instr-function can be called so that it starts at a certain position (first parameter). So loop over the content of a cell until the search term is no longer found, by starting the search behind the position where the last occurence of the word was found. Also, you can pass a parameter to tell InStr to compare the strings case insensitive (vbTextCompare) so that you don't need to use UCase.
I changed your code a little bit and added the loop:
Dim searchWords() As String, searchWord
searchWords = Split(strSearch, ",")

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In userRange
    For Each searchWord In searchWords
        searchWord = Trim(searchWord)
        If searchWord <> "" Then
            Dim searchLen As Long
            searchLen = Len(searchWord)
            Dim p As Long
            p = InStr(1, cell.Value, searchWord, vbTextCompare)
            Do While p > 0
                cell.Characters(p, searchLen).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)
                p = InStr(p + searchLen, cell.Value, searchWord, vbTextCompare)
            Loop
        End If
    Next searchWord
Next cell

